# adding jquery validation dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I found where you can add jquery validation rules dynamically like this:

```
$("#ParentAdNumber").rules("add", { required: true });
```

But how do you attach and detach a related message to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#ParentAdNumber").rules("remove", "required");
```

From the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules

**Edit: messages**

Adding:

```
$("#ParentAdNumber").rules("add", {
    optionName: true,
    messages: {
        optionName: "message for optionName"
    }
});
```

Removing:

```
$("#ParentAdNumber").rules("remove", "messages");
```

Looking at the source code of Validation, it doesn't look like you can remove specific messages...

Comment: Thx, figured that part out too, but it's the messages i'd like to add to the rules is what i can't figure out

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the help. Was that in the documentation?

Comment: So if I need to remove the rule I don't need to be concerned about removing the message, do I understand?

Comment: That was in the documentation. I believe you are correct: you don't need to remove the message.

Answer (score 4):

Simple!

```
$("#ParentAdNumber").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "Required input"
    }
});
```

you can change the message storing the rule:

```
var objRule = $("#ParentAdNumber").rules();
```

Changing:

```
objRule.messages.required = "New message";
```

and Re-applying:

```
$("#ParentAdNumber").rules("add", objRule);
```

Comment: Worth pointing out you have to define the message first for this to work (the first code snippet is required)

Answer (score 3):

This should do it....

```
.rules("add", {required: true, messages: {required: "Required input")}
```