# Removing datebox validations

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove JQuery validations in script?? I have 2 dateboxes and not able to remove the "required" thing and also unable to disable this field. I tried, `removeClass("required", true)` and also `document.getElementById("#element").disabled= true`. please advice!

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding jquery validation dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878841/adding-jquery-validation-dynamically)

Comment: No. I checked it. And I also tried ("#element").rules('remove');

Comment: you need to specify the name of the rule: `$("#element").rules('remove', 'required');`

Comment: I did this too..it gives me error: : $("#fromdd").rules is not a function

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

but element should be id.

```
document.getElementById("element").disabled= true
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it solved with this lines:

```
("element").datebox((disabled:true));
("element").datebox((required:false));
```